# Reference to self (this) inside CustomElement

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I'm using this [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) to implement a custom element in JavaScript. The `self` variable however references to `Window` inside my methods unless I call `const self = this` first.

Can anybody kindly explain why that is to me and perhaps suggest a better way to access the custom element instance within methods?

```
class DocumentPreview extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(self, documents) {
    self = super(self);
    self.documents = documents || [];
    self.innerHTML = Handlebars.templates['document_preview']();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    // if I don't do this first ...
    const self = this;   // <<----------------------------------
    console.log("connected now");
    document.addEventListener('mqttsub', function(event) {
      // ... onMessage is undefined here:
      self.onMessage(event.detail);
    });
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    console.log("disconnected");
  }

  onMessage(message) {
    // Same story ...
    const self = this;   // <<----------------------------------
    Promise.resolve(true)
    .then(json("/documents/"))
    .then(ds => ds
      .filter(x => x.name==message.payload)
      .reduce((x, y) => y, undefined)
    )
    .then(d => json(sprintf("/document/%d/", d.id))())
    // ... here:
    .then(d => self.renderDocuments(d))
    .catch(console.log);
  }

  renderDocuments(d) {
    console.log('render', d);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `self` parameter in the constructor wouldn't be accessible to other methods, that's a basic scope issue. If you're using arrow functions as in `onMessage()` you don't need the `self` variable, you can just use `this` directly. For a non-arrow function as in your event listener callback you can either do what you've shown or use `.bind(this)` with that callback and then `this` instead of `self` inside the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the methods `onMessage()` and `renderDocuments()` in the constructor using `bind()` as in `this.methodName = this.methodName.bind(this)`. With this you'll be able to access properties and methods via `this`.

```
class DocumentPreview extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(documents) {
    super();

    this.documents = documents || [];
    this.innerHTML = Handlebars.templates['document_preview']();

    this.onMessage = this.onMessage.bind(this);
    this.renderDocuments = this.renderDocuments.bind(this);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    document.addEventListener('mqttsub', this.onMessage);
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    console.log("disconnected");
  }

  onMessage(event) {
    const { detail: message } = event;

    Promise.resolve(true)
      .then(json("/documents/"))
      .then(ds => ds
        .filter(x => x.name==message.payload)
        .reduce((x, y) => y, undefined)
      )
      .then(d => json(sprintf("/document/%d/", d.id))())
      // ... here:
      .then(d => this.renderDocuments(d))
      .catch(console.log);
  }

  renderDocuments(d) {
    console.log('render', d);
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Great, and on top it improved significantly the readability. Quick one: what do you call this construction in JS: `const { detail: message } = event;` Is there a particular name to this kind of pattern matching?

Comment: OP's question was surrounding at a basic level not having to assign `this` to a variable inside of each method. The `bind()` approach should help with this by ensuring class methods are bound have the desired scope.

Comment: @沖原ハーベスト This is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) available in ES6. In this case it's unpacking the variable with key `detail` and assigning an alias/name of `message` to it. Thanks!

Comment: Much obliged ^ _ ^!

Comment: @nnnnnn You're absolutely right, totally missed that. Thank you for pointing that out, I'll get that updated to call `this.renderDocuments(d)` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the `this` keyword, refers to the current function's context.

```
document.addEventListener('mqttsub', function(event) {
  // this here corresponds to your function(event) {...} context
  this.onMessage(event.detail); // Will fail
});
```

One easy way to fix this is to use an arrow function. Arrow functions use the outer context by default.

```
document.addEventListener('mqttsub', (event) => {
  // this here corresponds to the outer context = your class
  this.onMessage(event.detail);
});
```

Otherwise you can also bind the context

```
document.addEventListener('mqttsub', (function(event) {
  this.onMessage(event.detail);
}).bind(this)); // Set the function context to be the class context
```